# iPhone 4 car kit for sound and video recording, and charging

Tags: iphone, mount, audio

I need a kit that I can mount in my car on the dashboard where I can do the following with my iPhone 4G:

- Use GPS
- Record Video from the forward facing camera (toward me) or the rear facing camera (away from me / through the front windshield)
- Make phone calls hands free (using the speaker phone or the headphones kit that comes with the iPhone or with a [Casette Adapter for iPhone](http://bit.ly/hN5hYO))

Is there a mount that I can use for this?

Comment: seems like you just want a mount that doesn't block the camera.

Comment: @Raj The link is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you'd like to save some money, check this search query at DealExtreme: [iPhone dash mount](http://www.dx.com/c/automobiles-motorcycles-799/car-gps-719/gps-holders-704) - there is a huge range, and for great prices too.

I've purchased plenty of things from them before, and it's all been surprisingly good stuff, especially considering the price.

Answer (score 2):

Xtand Go iPhone Car Mount

http://www.xtand.net/xtandgo.html
[image]

Comment: The link is broken